# Forever is truncating logs

Tags: node.js, logging, debian, syslog, forever

I've been using forever for a long time but recently it started to behave a little bit weird: everything is ok except for the logs.

I used to run `forever start /path/to/app.js` and everything was fine. Even for huge logs (1-2 gigs).

But I currently have an app, a very busy web app and the log is being truncated every 3-4 hours. The size is not that big, 80-120 megs actually.

After realising this I decided to try (unsuccessfully though) starting forever with options: `forever --append -o /path/to/out.log -e /path/to/error.log start /path/to/app.js` but the problem persists.

I really don't know what to do.
Any thoughts??
Thanks!!

Versions:

- node v0.12.7
- npm 2.11.3
- forever v0.15.1
- 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u6 (2015-11-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux

UPDATE1:

- BTW: I have plenty of hard disk an memory available

UPDATE2:

I found a related Issue (https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/106#issuecomment-116933382) and beging testing with the following command: `forever -a -l >(logger -t fileteTrackchile) start /path/to/app.js` So far so good, but it will store log information in `/var/log/user.log`, `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages`. It's the same information so it would be better to save it only once.

I'll leave it running for a couple of days and see if it works or not.

UPDATE3 (FINAL):

The problem had nothing to do with forever, nor winston. I didn't realise that the files were so big that the log viewer was only showing part of it. The confusing part is that the first line (past) was truncated by the viewer (OSX Console) what led me to think that the file itself was truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with forever, nor winston. I didn't realise that the files were so big that the log viewer was only showing part of it. The confusing part is that the first line (past) was truncated by the viewer (OSX Console) what led me to think that the file itself was truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first approach, unexpected log truncation is often caused by log rotation. However, you didn't mention rotating your logs.

Your second approach is to send the logs to a `syslog` daemon using the `logger` client.

Your logging is then ending up in three logs due your `syslog` configuration.

Try this solution. Create a file named `/etc/rsyslog.d/10-fileteTrackchile.conf`.

In the file, add these lines:

```
$template JustMsg,"%msg:2:10000%\n"
if $programname == 'fileteTrackchile' then /var/log/fileteTrackchile.log;JustMsg
if $programname == 'fileteTrackchile' then stop
```

Then:

```
service rsyslog stop
service rsyslog start
```

Because the file name starts with `10`, it will get run before other configuration.

The logic instructs the logging for your app be logged to a particular file, unmodified, and then stop further processing by `rsyslog`, so the logging doesn't end up in the three other files you mentioned.

You may also wish to create `/etc/logrotate.d/fileteTrackchile` with contents like this:

```
/var/log/fileteTrackchile.log
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                service rsyslog reload >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}
```

See `man logrotate` for the details of those log rotation options.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, this worked! but I still have two big problems; 1) if I restart the application I need to restart rsyslog and for the latter I need root privileges what makes everything more complicated from an operational standpoint, and 2) I wasn't using logrotate at all, actually I was using the default location for the logs /home/someUser/.forever to store them in the first place. That was a perfect solution for me till this truncation problem came up.

Comment: rsyslog should never need to be restarted.  You don't have to use logrotate to manage your log rotation. You can rotate your logs however you like.